# PHP - maintain cookie after clearing cache

Tags: php, cookies

I've to restrict access to a specific page if it's been visited more than once a day, so I did the following:

```
<?php

    if(! isset($_COOKIE["VisitCount"])){
        setcookie("VisitCount", "1", strtotime('today 23:59'));
    }

    if($_COOKIE["VisitCount"] > 1){
        echo "<script>alert('You can only play once a day'); location.href='http://example.com';</script>";
        exit();
    }
    else {
        setcookie("VisitCount", ($_COOKIE["VisitCount"] + 1), strtotime('today 23:59'));
    }

?>
```

But the user can clear the cache and enter that page again. How can I change it so users are blocked for the remaining of the day?

EDIT:

I added a 'time' column on my table, I suppose I have to use an If statement to check if the last time is within the last 24 hours, but I don't know how to do it.

Also, the access is limited to once a day, but not exactly every 24 hours since it should reset at midnight, would this require a different code? or the one I provided above could work (slightly modified)?

Comment: I would try with something persistent, like db storage.

Comment: So log the user in a database or similar that their last access was date x. If current date isn't x, then allow access.

Comment: You can't persist cookies like that. If you could, it would defeat the purpose of being able to clear the cache. Your only bet is to require login and limit to once per login. But nothing would stop someone from having multiple logins unless they were like pay-for login.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side logging is not a good idea for limit something. You have to limit it server-side with an unique property of the client.

For this purpose, you should use the IP address of the client and write it into a database table with the last access timestamp. Sure, the user can change his IP address probably, but this is more difficult than deleting the cookies/cache.

Another possibility than the IP address is not given - manipulation is possible very easy. There is no 100% chance to limit to one request/action.

Comment: Outside of a LAN, maniuplating an IP address for TCP is relatively hard (you can't spoof it but you can use an anonymization service)- but it far from suitable as a unique identifier of users.

Comment: Yes, but you can change user agents etc. very easy. I do not speak of manipulating but simply getting a new one. Here in Germany, you can reconnect your router within the most providers and get instantly (~30 seconds) a new IP address. Furthermore, you can simply use your smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't enforce such a restriction.

Using cookies only works as long as the user does not delete the cookie.

Same for other client side stored data.

You can make it (significantly) harder for someone to delete the identifier you associate with the client using [evercookies or browser fingerprinting](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/im-currently-spending-significant.html)

You can't use the IP address (free WIFI is everywhere and using Tor you don't even need to go for a walk).

You could force the user to register with an email address and require the email address to be validated (by emailing a OTP to the address) but then you can only enforce one game per email address per day - how hard is it to get a free email address?